# How are policies, norms, and rules are determined in this community?

Tags: discussion, support, policy, meta, faq-proposed

**Many** people, including some moderators, have expressed to me the following, which is an excerpt from a moderator's comment, **many** times in **many** places:

> ... the guidelines are guidelines and not rules. Each community has its own norms and practices.

Although I am not sure whether the Stack Exchange community team endorses such a viewpoint, let us accept it. Now, I wonder how community norms (policies, rules, or whatever you call) are determined by the community. Specifically, the following questions arises:

- Are norms determined in a ***completely democratic*** way; that is, are they determined by **most** users?
- Is there any ***veto*** in determining community norms; for example, if most users endorse a norm, may moderators or a group of community leaders (highly active meta users) veto such an endorsement?
- Do users ***have to*** express their agreement/disagreement with a norm by voting on Meta; for example, if many users endorse a norm by their treatment on the main site, will it not be regarded as their agreement/disagreement with a norm?

---

EDIT (by [Gerry Myerson](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/8269/gerry-myerson)): Here is an example of a community norm contradicting the written guidelines determined by the Stack Exchange community team: a moderator wrote,

When you raise a large number of "no longer needed" flags on ancient posts, you are asking us to take some time out of our day to investigate something which (almost certainly) will not impact the overall site. **One or two "no longer needed" flags on ancient posts is fine**, but, as I recall, there were a lot of these flags. If I was the one who handled your flags, the goal was to send the message "please don't raise so many flags".

Comment: This comment can be entirely wrong or correct. If you are using stackoverflow then there has been releasion of [collectives](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408585/beta-release-of-collectives-on-stack-overflow?cb=1) which has highly been downvoted and disagreed but still is present. So the rules are entirely made by the staff and hardly are action taken. Do remember this might not be correct too

Comment: @Jitendra, the question is about math.stackexchange, not about stackoverflow.

Comment: It's hard to answer your questions in the abstract, Later. Is there some particular norm you are interested in?

Comment: @GerryMyerson ya I know but we can relate many rules

Comment: @GerryMyerson Let us keep this post general. As you may know, when I saw some norms contradicting the written guidelines determined by the Stack Exchange community team, I was told by the community leaders, including some moderators, that community norms are determined by the community *itself*, so I asked this post to know its procedure and details. However, if you need some example, [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33646/656359) is one (A moderator stated the related community norm in a comment).

Comment: Later, The world is not, and most certainly neither SE, SO, nor math.stackexchange, is a black and white endeavor, nor is any human institution black and white.  Please don't try to make it so; I'd rather not have the human race controlled by binary robots.

Comment: I count ten comments by moderators at that link, Later. I'm not going to read all of them, just to find the one you had in mind, when you could just as easily copy it & paste it into your question here.

Comment: @Later: Community norms are indeed determined by the community itself, but I wouldn't say that there's a *procedure* involved. Things are much more fluid and unspoken than you seem to make out.

Comment: I think its good to try to get things in writing, but not everything can be written down clearly. Your questions are also too absolute, and oddly phrased. If I agree with a "norm", i do not **have to** find or make a post about it and upvote it... And anyway, most users by a long shot do not visit math.meta, and if they do, its likely just for the mathjax help posts

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry, I did not mention the link of the comment because my comment would have become too long; I meant [this comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33646/am-i-as-a-comment-flagger-a-waster-of-the-moderators-time?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment154112_33646), in which the moderator mentioned the norm saying that "one or two no longer needed flags on ancient posts is fine. Also I have mentioned another example in my previous comment.

Comment: Don't worry, Later – I did it for you.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I am not (and was not) worried. You could also mention the other example I mentioned in the comment for you; I think that is be a *better* example. By the way, thanks for your edit.

Comment: You're welcome. But I've showed you the way; I'll let you do the further edit.

Comment: I am not sure that example is appropriate. If you check the mod office chat room, you can see that even the mod team has different opinion concerning how those flag should be dealt with.

Comment: Indeed, i consider your previous post one way to form/test the comminity norm.

Comment: I've been outspoken in my criticism of the moderators and indeed I agree that the aversion to "rules" rather than "guidelines" is nothing short of *bizarre*, but comparing yourself to Galileo is nothing short of comical

Comment: @JackGallagher How about offending/silencing people having different opinions? Is it not *nothing short of comical*, or tragic?

Comment: Later, please stop moving the target: I.e., editing to try to stay relevant. Please stop repeating the perpetual narrative that you are a victim.  If anything, you're self-sabotaging yourself on this site; I think you undermine realizing your goals;

Comment: Later, you are tenaciously stuck on your self-narrative of victimhood.  We are tired of the repeated accusations.  Your behavior, and words, alone, are responsible for the consequences you experience.   Which you then blame others for.  But it starts and ends with you.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed - in Later's comment they clarified "I was told by the community leaders...that community norms are determined by the community itself, so I asked this post to know its procedure and details", which is a decent question. It can be frustrating and confusing when people say "the community believes *this*" when in fact they mean "some people on meta believe *this*".

Comment: (I am aware of this user's other meta activity, but this question is much improved, both in content and format. It is not perfect, and I did have to quote their clarification to find a clear version of their question, but also there is nothing to be lost by treating it as an honest question and giving it an honest answer. I am not entirely sure how to verbalise how these "norms" are decided & am not convinced by Joe's comment of "Things are much more fluid and unspoken than you seem to make out". Sometime, I wonder if it is simply certain groups shouting louder and being more active on meta.)

Comment: @user1729  I agree that it is much improved, but they keep invoking the narrative that they see themselves as being censored and persecuted due to their thoughts and opinions; they are convinced that they are being suppressed on this site, and identify with persons not at all analogous.  Hence my comments here, that their behavior and their own writing,  is responsible for where they are at.  Further more, The very same theme undergirding this question, has been present in most of their questions.  So, it amounts perseverating on this site.

Comment: @amWhy I don't think this theme is in this question, although is in their comments (posted after the question was heavily downvoted). I think the question should be judged in terms of the question itself not in terms of the user who asked it (within reason), and so I do not think to should be closed.

Comment: If Later's goal is to divide the community, then Later will be pleased to know that there are currently three votes to reopen, and two to delete.

Comment: Most users do not even come on meta, because they don't believe in the importance of the meta site. I wasn't on meta for a large part of my MSE life because I felt I was doing what users would be expected to do, guideline-wise, and didn't have the will (or maturity or patience) to have, let alone express an opinion here. I just wanted to do mathematics! Another point is that meta is full of disagreements , even if cordial (and sometimes not), while MSE is definitely a "nicer" place full of things to learn and nice answers to see. I expect this to be the chief, if not only reason.

Comment: The relevance of the above comment is that most policies get voted on by a "meta" (and not "main") majority. Now it is up to you as to whether this is "democratic" or not.  I cannot comment on the second point. For the third, I think moderators would be keeping track of trends that are displayed towards norms , but I'm not sure any kind of actions or changes of norms would precede a meta post and a "meta" community vote.    More important changes could be tagged as feature requests so that they rise to more prominence. EoQS has been viewed 6K times due to good publicity.

Answer (score 1):

(The following is [Teresa Lisbon's comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33857/how-are-policies-norms-and-rules-are-determined-in-this-community#comment155669_33857), which I will post it as an answer.)

Most policies get voted on by a "meta" (and not "main") majority. Now it is up to you as to whether this is "democratic" or not. I cannot comment on the second point. For the third, I think moderators would be keeping track of trends that are displayed towards norms , but I'm not sure any kind of actions or changes of norms would precede a meta post and a "meta" community vote. More important changes could be tagged as feature requests so that they rise to more prominence. EoQS has been viewed 6K times due to good publicity.

Comment: (I edited to correct the spelling of my name) Thank you for the answer , I had made the comment when the question was closed. I can't think of ways to elaborate on what I said (other than the comment above the one I made as well). Maybe one more sentence : Not everything is black-and-white, and disagreements only serve to highlight the gray areas, so these will occur(on meta posts) and are good to see as well. If people care, we go forward. I can't say it's more complicated than that.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Why are your edits/comments merged with Teresa Lisbon’s?

Comment: @ТymaGaidash That's my old name.